# Using DataFrame to subtract list from another list, where one has a nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating an inventory management system in python.

Say we have an inventory like this:
`inventory = [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 30}, {"product_id": 1, "quantity": 25}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 25}]`

A user places an order like this: 
`order = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 4}]}`

Then ideally, the console would print this:
`inventory = [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 28}, {"product_id": 1, "quantity": 25}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 21}]`

So far, I've been trying to do this operation with DataFrame from the Pandas module:

```
import Pandas as pd

inventory = [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 30}, {"product_id": 1, "quantity": 25}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 25}]
order = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 4}]}

def process_order(order):
    global inventory
    df1=pd.DataFrame(order) #Something needs to go here to point to the nested dict, right?
    df2=pd.DataFrame(inventory)
    dfsum=pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('product_id').difference().reset_index()
    inventory=dfsum.to_dict(orient='records')
    print(inventory)
```

But that's returning an error. 
edit: This is the full error

```
  File "league.py", line 40, in <module>
    process_order(order)
  File "league.py", line 20, in process_order
    dfsum=pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('product_id').difference().reset_index()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6525, in groupby
    dropna=dropna,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 533, in __init__
    dropna=self.dropna,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 786, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'product_id'
```

I know I'm close, and I know the error has something to do with pointing to that nested dict in the `order` list.
 How do I get it to print out the resulting inventory like this?
`inventory = [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 28}, {"product_id": 1, "quantity": 25}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 21}]`

Comment: "But that's returning an error." What error?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga KeyError: 'product_id'

Comment: What's the full error message, including the stack trace? Please, that includes a ton of useful information.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've added the full error into the question as an edit (it had too many characters to fit in a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to make a dataframe from "order" itself. The thing you want to subtract from inventory is `order["requested"]`. Take the data both of these datasets have in common ("product_id") and make it the index to the dataframes. Now subtraction will subtract like-indexed values. Since the order doesn't contain all possible items in inventory, you can use the `subtract` method to fill the other values.

Setup dataframes with "product_id" as index

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> inventory = [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 30}, {"product_id": 1, "quantity": 25}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 25}]
>>> order = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id": 2, "quantity": 4}]}
>>> 
>>> inventory_df = pd.DataFrame(inventory).set_index("product_id")
>>> inventory_df
            quantity
product_id          
0                 30
1                 25
2                 25
>>> order_df = pd.DataFrame(order["requested"]).set_index("product_id")
>>> order_df
            quantity
product_id          
0                  2
2                  4
```

Build a series holding the new quantities in inventory

```
>>> new_quantity = inventory_df["quantity"].subtract(order_df["quantity"], fill_value=0.0)
>>> new_quantity
product_id
0    28.0
1    25.0
2    21.0
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```

Make sure you aren't going to be sued for delivering too few products

```
>>> if (new_quantity < 0).any():
...     print("bad news")
...
```

Set the new quantity

```
>>> inventory_df["quantity"] = new_quantity
>>> inventory_df
            quantity
product_id          
0               28.0
1               25.0
2               21.0
>>>
```